# Guard with where in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

In Swift 2, we can easy add where to a guard statment

```
guard let varA = 1 where varB == 2 else {return}
```

But the `where` removed in swift 3, how can I do like that in Swift 3 ?

Answer (score 7):

Use `,` to separate `condition` and remove `where`

```
guard let varA = 1, varB == 2 else {return}
```